# Dynamic image creation/manipulation in AppEngine?

Tags: image, google-app-engine

I have not been able to track down an answer on this. I'd like to be able to manipulate or create images to then compile into a video. I'm starting to think this is just not a good fit for GAE. I wanted to do this in Python but doesn't look like that is possible without C support. Even with Java I'm seeing conflicting information about what is possible.

Does anyone know for sure if there are any fully supported image libraries for Python or Java?

Answer (score 0):

You're right - anything that involves heavy image manipulation isn't a good fit for App Engine - especially video encoding. Consider writing a service that does this on something such as EC2, and calling it from App Engine when needed.